# how to add condition if directory already exist in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am creating a directory now I want to add a condition if the directory already exists.
**This is my code**

```
                    if(name == ''){  
                        print('empty controller');
                      }
                      else{
                        print('succcci');

                        var path = "storage/emulated/0/zip/$name";
                        new Directory(path).create();
                      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists()`:

```
var path = "storage/emulated/0/zip/$name";

if(!await Directory(path).exists()){
   //need to create directory
   Directory(path).create();
}
```